# how to send mail to all users when new post data is entered in database in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, notifications, laravel-8

i want to send all users notification when a user create a new post in database the notification should go to all the users as new post created

```php
<?php
    
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Notifications\PostNotificationforAll;

class Postnotification extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'post:notification';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Post notification for all users';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $users= User::all();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $user->notify(new PostNotificationforAll());
        }
    }
}
```

can any help me out what condition should i use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\User;

class PostObserver
{
      public function created(Post $post)
      {
          $users = User::where(...)->get();

          // Send the notifications
          Notification::send($users, new Postnotification($post));
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using observer
When new post created you can run event using observer class

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\Post;

class PostObserver
{
     /**
      * Handle the Rate "created" event.
      *
      * @param Post $post
      * @return void
      */
      public function created(Post $post)
      {
          event(new PostCreated($post));
      }
}
```

The in PostCreated event you can listen to it then in listener you can notifiy users with this post

You can read more about observer from laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers)

Answer (score 0):

- You can do it with creating a new mail class

  php artisan make:mail NotifyUsers
- Then make a mail.blade.php have your html template mail which send to users with $user : is a user name who created a post , and $post_title : is a title of the post created

=> In Mail/NotifyUsers

```
     class NotifyUsers extends Mailable
    {
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user,$post_title;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user,$post_title)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->post_title = $post_title;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.mail')->with(['user' => $user , 'post_title' => $post_title]);
    }
  }
```

- Then go to controller which have a store posts function and put this code

  ```
  foreach (User::all('email') as $email) {

    Mail::to($email)->send(new NotifyUsers(auth()->user()->name , $request->post_title));

      }
  ```